# My file isnt copying properly in perl

Tags: perl, copy, file-handling

I'm writing a program that is supposed to get data from another file that's put in at the command line, run a cipher on it, then copy what data it outputs to another file but it isn't saving the data properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $userinput;
my $filename = "$ARGV[0]";
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename) or die "Couldn't open '$filename' $!";
open(my $oh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', "$filename.dec") or die "Couldn't save '$filename' $!";
$userinput= <$fh>;
sub decodecaesar {
    my ($message, $key) = @_;
    $key = 26 - $key;
    $message =~ s/([A-Z])/chr(((ord(uc $1) - 65 + $key) % 26) + 65)/geir;
 }
 my $user = decodecaesar($userinput, 1);
 print "$user";

 while(<$fh>){
    print $oh $user;
 }
 close($fh);
 close($oh);
```

It is copying something to the file as whenever I put something into the file it gets overwritten with an empty file while the file its reading from is not empty and works properly. Where did I screw up?

Comment: I don't understand your description of what's wrong.  The code you show will print to `$oh` the string `$user` as many times as there are lines on `$fh` (and without any newlines).

Comment: Pardon, let me try and clarify. Its supposed to take something lets say from the file data.txt while the data in the file just contains "BCD"  run the cipher on it which would cause it spit back "ABC" and then save that into the file named data.txt.dec however its not saving anything there. Does that help?

Comment: Btw,  generally one wants to `chomp` user input. While it may not matter, here you get inconsistent returns: the original input with the newline if there is no match, but the changed string without the newline if there is a match.

Comment: Ah.  If the file has _one line_, that's gone after the first `<$fh>` and there's nothing left to read on the `$fh` for the `while (<$fh>)`.  So the print to `$oh` never runs.  If there were more lines the `while` would go through them but `$user` has been only made once. Perhaps move `my $user = ...` into the `while` loop?  Like `print $oh decodecaesar($_,1)`

Comment: (the file gets truncated once it's `open`ed for writing, regardless of whether it was written to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean to "translate" from input to output line by line you need to do that inside the loop

```
while (my $userinput = <$fh>) {
    chomp $userinput;
    print $oh decodecaesar($userinput, 1);
}
```

Note that using `$line` is a common and good convention for naming a variable that takes a line from a file.  I left `$userinput` from the OP in case it is meant to convey that the file contains user input in some specific sense. Still, I recommend to reconsider.

In this case you can also make use of the [*default input and pattern-searching space*, `$_`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$_)

```
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    print $oh decodecaesar($_, 1);
}
```

I am not suggesting this, just noting it.  There is *nothing* wrong with a nicely named variable.

---

A few notes on the code

- No need to declare (`my $userinput;`) and assign separately (`$userinput = ...`)
- No need to double-quote a variable like `"$ARGV[0]"` (and it may lead to subtle trouble)
- Always check input, `my $input = $ARGV[0] || usage();` (or provide default)
- Note the [open pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/open.html)

  ```
  use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
  ```

  and now all streams will be encoded/decoded so you don't have to do it for each `open`. This can be overridden as needed.